# Is the name 'class' from 'Complexity class' came from ZF set theory?

Tags: complexity-theory, terminology

I just want to know if people in the complexity initiated the name 'class' because the term 'class' in Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory or not?

For me, I assume the answer is Yes; because it doesn't seem right that it was coincidence and we use all time set theories tools to prove inclusions. But what made me asked this question is that I never found a reference in Sipser and Barak-Arrora that 'class' came from ZF-set theory.

Class in ZF-set theory is a collections of sets that have some common things. For example: Class P has set of languages which all of them are bounded by polynomial of the size of the input. Note that set is different from Class, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139330/what-is-the-difference-between-a-class-and-a-set).

Comment: According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/class), a class is "A group, collection, category or set sharing characteristics or attributes." In set theory, *class* has a particular technical meaning, but a complexity class is not a proper class.

Comment: The reason that "set theory tools" are used to prove inclusions is that *inclusion* is a set-theoretic concept. Set theory is an underlying language of mathematics. It's not used in a particularly deep way in complexity theory, though the technique of diagonalization is borrowed from set theory.